# How to achieve this smooth zig zag effect for these lines?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-effects

I tried to achieve this below simple effect in Adobe Illustrator.

[image]

...but my result is a not exactly that I expect and it's a little different from the original image. I've tried **Zigzag** effect and applied it to both selected lines but the below line waves should be more tighter in high points of the waves (mentioned by the red arrows), so allow the lines to be closer to get fit like in the original image without I have to  decrease the width stroke of the below line or something else.

[image]

Comment: make one zigzag line. Then offset a copy of that on both sides.

Comment: @joojaa, I've tried it, but the result was the same I did with the effect and didn't get like the original.

Comment: @joojaa, I used Offset Path (Object > Path > Offset Path...) while the zigzag line is selected, but didn't work as I expect.

Comment: well its probably safe to say that you do not want to mix effects and actions that way. Either use the offset from effects menu. Or expand the effect and then use the object path action. Because nixing concept causes it to not do it in the sequence you expect

Comment: @joojaa, selecting Offset effect from the Effects menu is worked and produce result like the "Scott's" result in his answer and it's fine and can be a correct answer and solution,  but Billy's method by Pattern Brush is produce better result in my case. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Draw a single line with a thick black stroke, and apply the zig-zag effect
2. Expand Appearance, then Expand again, ungroup it and delete the centre path
3. Select the shape and set no fill and a black stroke
4. Select and delete all the segments except one piece of the wave
5. Drag it to the brushes panel and make a pattern brush
6. Apply the pattern brush to a drawn path

[image]

or apply the brush to a shape

[image]

Another method which might work for you if you need to keep it as all live path effects, is to add the zig-zag effect to a single path as before, and in the Appearance panel, add a white stroke which is smaller than the black stroke. This could be useful for example if you need to adjust the zig-zag effect.

[image]

You could then add this to your graphic styles, and apply it to any object.

Note: The only downside of keeping this as a live zig-zag effect is that if you have segments of different length, the zig-zag will be squished or stretched. This can be avoided using the brush method above.

Comment: Well done @Billy, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's *not* two paths. It's one path with two sides. There's a difference.

Just use a single path and expand...

[image]

Comment: Cool idea!, and like the Appearance panel and its tricks, In my case the "Billy Kerr's" answer is closer to the result I wish to produce and avoid sharp high points inside the shape, still like your method to this kind of situation and works well, thanks Scott.

Comment: Glad you sorted it `:)` .. the "sharper high points" are merely due to the zig zag frequency. Lower the frequency and those inner point aren't as sharp, that's all.

Comment: Thank you Scott and You right, also without changing the "Zig zag" settings (Zig zag window > Size box), just by dragging the line shape to make longer could get smoother high points, and when line shape is shorter, produce those sharp points.

p.s
I hope we can select more than answer for a question in StackExchange forum to select your answer too.